# when image not found show default image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have an mvc 4 application running on iis 7.5. The application produces a product catalogue with images assigned to each product.

At times some products do not have any images assigned to them and in this situation I would like to include a placeholder image rather than nothing. It is not until run time and when the 404 occurs that the image does not exist.

I am thinking of setting up a url rewrite rule in IIS where if a 404 is returned from an image that matches the condition, the default image is shown. I have a couple questions on this:

Is it possible and if so how?
Are there performance issues around doing this?
Is there any other way I could achieve the above?

Answer (score 1):

Good question. My first thought would be to find out if the file exists on the server. I'm assuming this is not as easy as having a database column for the image.

Maybe you have a scenario where you look into a folder where the image would be the same name as the productId (or something like that). You could use System.IO.FileExists() in order to find out if the file was there. This might not be incredibly efficient.

Another idea might be to look at the directory where the files exist and put them in some sort of Dictionary. You could store that in the application Cache. You could look at the Cache before rendering the image. Of course you want a want a way of refreshing that dictionary (ie a product image get's uploaded for that product)

I don't know about how the rewrite would work. I would think you could do a little work on your end-- in order to avoid doing that.

```
<img src="(@Dictionary[key] != null ? Model.Image : Model.EmptyImage)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to handle this with IIS you could use the custom 404 error page configuration.
I don't know about the performance with this solution but I don't see a reason why it would be an issue.

1. Setup a `Virtual Directory` containing all your images (let's call it `my_images`).
2. Add your generic picture at the virtual directory root (so this picture is available using the url `http://yourwebsite.com/my_images/generic.jpg`).
3. In IIS manager select your `my_images` virtual directory and under `Error Pages` edit the 404 custom error page as following:

   [image: 404]

You should now have your generic picture when a 404 error is triggered when trying to access a resource under your virtual directory `my_images`.

**Limitation:**

The custom 404 error page is not limited to the image format so any request triggering the 404 error under your virtual directory will render the generic image.
If you want to test using `localhost`, you need to click on `Edit Feature Settings...` and change the value to `Custom error pages`:

[image: features]